# How can I share NSUserDefaults between two applications in OS X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I'm writing an application that will be submitted to the Mac App Store.  As part of the application there is a helper/background application.  My main application needs to be able to write persistent settings to NSUserDefaults.  My helper application, which is presumably running in the background, needs to be notified of those changes and then be able to read the new NSUserDefaults so that it can configure itself appropriately.

The notification portion of it I'm not too worried about.  I see that NSUserDefaults has a notification named NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification that is sent when persistent defaults are changed.  If that doesn't work there are always distributed notifications that I can use.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to make the defaults from the main application become accessible to the background/helper application.  I've fiddled around with the following methods of NSUserDefaults but I'm not getting anywhere.

```
 - (void)addSuiteNamed:(NSString *)suiteName
 - (void)setPersistentDomain:(NSDictionary *)domain forName:(NSString *)domainName
```

Could somebody please show me code for both the main application and the background/helper application that works?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [addSuiteNamed:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/addSuiteNamed%3a) method of NSUserDefaults.

```
- (void)addSuiteNamed:(NSString *)suiteName
```

This will work only for reading settings, not for writing.

Comment: I need more detail please.  That method has very little documentation.  I'm looking for specific examples of how the main application should write the preferences and then how the helper/background application can read those preferences.

Comment: I figured out the issue.  Both my main application and the client application were configured to utilize app sandboxing.  It would appear that if the helper application is configured to use sandboxing then it is unable to read the NSUserDefaults that the main application writes.  If I disable app sandboxing then I'm able to read the default set by the main application so long as I first use the 'addSuiteNamed:' method as suggested by Parag.